# How to set selection options in jQuery with the empty and append functions

Tags: jquery

With jQuery version 3.3, I set selection options with following two commands

```
$("#selection_input").empty();
$("#selection_input").append(data.options);
```

Can it be replaced with 1 command?

Thanks!

Comment: Why would you want to?  What is wrong with using these two functions?  It is easy to read and probably is faster than using one function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `.html()` to replace the contents. It will empty it first.

```
$("#selection_input").html(data.options);
```

Answer (score 2):

The answer is yes.  In the demonstration below, on mouse enter, a function is called that uses empty and append together to restore the options of the previously saved select options.

```js
function removeOptions($select) {
  var $optionsToRemove = $select.find('option:not(:selected)'); 
  $optionsToRemove.remove(); //remove
}

function setSelectCurrentState($select) {
  $select.data("currentOptions", $select.find('option'));
}

function restoreOptions($select) {
  var oldOptions = $select.data("currentOptions"); 
  if (oldOptions) {
    //This line of code uses empty and then append to restore the options
    $select.empty().append(oldOptions);
  }
}

$(document).ready(function() {
  var $hoverSelect = $('#hoverSelect');
  $hoverSelect.mouseleave(function() {
    setSelectCurrentState($hoverSelect); // save the current state
    removeOptions($hoverSelect); 
  });
  $hoverSelect.mouseenter(function() {
    restoreOptions($hoverSelect);
  });
});
```

```css
body {
  background-color: #99b;
}
form {
  width: 150px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
h1,
h2 {
  text-align: center;
}
#hoverSelect {
  width: 150px;
  height: 65px;
  font-size: 1.2em;
}
#hoverSelect:hover {
  height: 150px;
}
#wrapper {
  width: 100%;
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script> 
<h2>Hover to expand, click or shift click options to select, mouse out to minimize</h2>
<br />
<div id="wrapper">
  <form>
    <select id="hoverSelect" name="hoverSelect" multiple="multiple">
      <option value="1">One</option>
      <option value="2" class="two">Two</option>
      <option value="3">Three</option>
      <option value="4">Four</option>
      <option value="5">Five</option>
      <option value="6">Six</option>
    </select>
  </form>
</div>
<br />
<h2>Remembers the checked state of the options</h2>
```